# How to prevent Python from escaping special characters when reading a regex from a text file?

Tags: python, regex, file-io, python-3.x

I am reading a text file in Python that, among other things, contains pre-written regexes that will be used for matching later on. The text file is of the following format:

> ...
>
> --> Task 2
>
> Concatenate and print the strings "Hello, " and "world!" to the screen.
>
> --> Answer
>
> Hello, world!
>
> print(\"Hello,\s\"\s*+\s*\"world!\")
>
> --> Hint 1
>
> You can concatenate two strings with the + operator
>
> ...

User input is being accepted based on tasks and either executed in a subprocess to see a return value or matched against a regex. The issue, though, is that python's file.readline() will escape all special characters in the regex string (i.e. backslashes), giving me something that isn't useful.

I tried to read in the file as bytes and decode the lines using the 'raw_unicode_escape' argument (described as producing "a string that is suitable as raw Unicode literal in Python source code"), but no dice:

```
file.open(filename, 'rb')
for line in file:
  line = line.decode('raw_unicode_escape')
  ...
```

Am I going about this the completely wrong way?

Thanks for any and all help.

p.s. I found this question as well: [Issue while reading special characters from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483001/issue-while-reading-special-characters-from-file). However, I still have the same trouble when I use `file.open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python regex patterns are just plain old strings. There should be no problem with storing them in a file. Perhaps when you use `file.readline()` you are seeing escaped characters because you are looking at the `repr` of the line? That should not be an issue when you actually use the pattern as a regex however:

```
import re
filename='/tmp/test.txt'
with open(filename,'w') as f:
    f.write(r'\"Hello,\s\"\s*\+\s*\"world!\"')

with open(filename,'r') as f:
    pat = f.readline()
    print(pat)
    # \"Hello,\s\"\s*\+\s*\"world!\"
    print(repr(pat))
    # '\\"Hello,\\s\\"\\s*\\+\\s*\\"world!\\"'
    assert re.search(pat,'  "Hello, " +   "world!"')  # Shows match was found
```

Comment: This was a frustrating experience. You're correct, thank you; I was looking at repr(string).

Comment: And you *should* use repr(string), otherwise you are not getting an unambiguous representation of what's actually in your string. You just need to understand what is going on. Merely reading a file does *not* do any escaping or unescaping.

Comment: Thanks for the addition, John. I agree. I'm still relatively new to all this, and making mistakes like this definitely give me a better understanding of what's happening in the background.

Comment: Sheesh I've been banging on this for an hour now. Thanks for the clue stick.